# What's wrong with my method of counting the number of $7$s under $1000000$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need to find the number of $7$s if we write all the numbers from $1$ to $1000000$(so $77$, for example, counts as two $7$s and not one).

Here's what I did:

I split the problem into $7$ sections:

The number of $7$s in numbers with one seven: $\displaystyle \binom{7}{1}$$*$ $9^6$(number of ways to place one $7$ times the number of possible numbers we could make with each displacement. Note that leading zeros wouldn't be a problem since they would result in numbers with less than $7$ digits which we need)

The number of $7$s in numbers with two sevens:
$\displaystyle\binom{7}{2} * 9^5 * 2$(same logic, but we multiplied it by $2$ since there's two sevens)

...

So my answer would be $\sum_{i=1}^7 \displaystyle \binom{7}{i}9^ii$ but my textbook says the right answer is $600000$. I do understand its solution but I don't know why mine is wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be ${6 \choose i} $ because you have $6$ digits?

Comment: @kingW3 Ohhhh, that's right. I also counted $7$-digit numbers. Please add it as an answer so I could accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Also, each of the six digits is 7 for 10% of the million cases, so $6\cdot\frac{10^6}{10}$

Comment: Well, to begin with the numbers less than $1000000$ do *not* have $7$ digits; they have six digits so it should be $\sum_{i=1}^6{6\choose i}9^ii$.  Second "same logic, but we multiplied it by 2 since there's two sevens"  Why?  Why does having $2$ mean there are twice as many numbers?  Why would there be *any* more numbers?  And why are you doing things in terms of $9$?  There are $10$ digits.

Comment: Why are you even *trying* to do it that way?  If there is a $7$ in the $n$ position they other $5$ digits be any of $10^5$ combintaions.  So there are $10^5$ numbers with a $7$ in the the $n$ position.  That is $10^5$ sevens.  there are just as many sevens in each of the other positions. And as there are 6 positions there are $6*10^5$ sevens (or any other digits [except 0 {there $6*10^5$ zeros *and* blank opening spaces |if you start at 0 and end at 999999|}])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're counting $7$ digit numbers but you only need $6$.

Answer (score 0):

One.  the numbers $0$ to $999999$ (as $1000000$ doesn't have any $7$) have $6$ digits.  Not seven.

Three somehow you went from the power being $6-i$ to $i$.

$\sum_{k=1}^6 {6\choose k}9^{6-k}*k = 6*59049*1 + 15*6561*2 + 20*279*3 + 15*81*4 + 6*9*5 + 1*1*6=600000$

But why break it into seven cases?

If we count the number of times $7$ appears in the $n$ position there are $10^5$ ways the other digits can be.  So a $7$ will appear in the $n$ position $10^5$ times.  So the total number of $7$s that appear in any and all of the six positions will be $6*10^5$.

Interesting result though $\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k}(b-1)^{n-k}*k = n*b^{n-1}$ apparently.

Think you can prove that or give an argument why it'd be so?

Comment: Yeah it should've been $6-i$.m I forgot to add the $-i$. Well, the reason that I broke it into $7$ cases is that for combinatorics problems, I try to try a few approaches and analyze which one might be better, why they might be different, etc. Thanks for the solution! It was different from my textbook.